# Replace a string in a string array on Angular2

Tags: arrays, string, angular

I have a string array with strings like age ,gender,nationality. Need to replace **age** to **agexxxx**. So is there any method to replace a string in string array on angular?

```
this.segment=['age','Nationality','gender'];
```

Comment: Try this `['age','Nationality','gender'].map(w => w === 'age' ? 'agexxxx' : w);` If you want to modify the existing array, you can use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go :

```js
var segment=['age','Nationality','gender'];

var changed = segment.map(seg => seg.replace('age', 'agexx') );


console.log('Original --->' ,segment);
console.log('Changed --->' ,changed);
```

Comment: @Vickie , Glad to know , Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
for(var i=0; i < this.segment.length; i++) {
 this.segment[i] = this.segment[i].replace('age', 'agexx');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let a = ['age','hello','world']
a.splice(0, 1,'agexxx');
alert(a)
```

reference : [Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)